# Microsoft Teams tasks.submitTask does not work on IOS

Tags: microsoft-teams

We have a published app in the Teams App Store.

We have implemented BarCode scanner feature in the task module and it is working fine. However when code is scanned we want to close the task module right away by executing **microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask();**

This method is working great on Android and it closes the task module window, but it does not work on IOS.
On IOS we are receiving this error:

> This call is not allowed in the 'content' context.

We have also tried to add parameters **result and appIds** but it didn't help.

**IOS app version:**

```
Microsoft Teams
Version: 3.16.0
Build: 3.16.77.2021163502/1004 (general)
Calling Version: 2021.34.01.8
Release Branch: 2021Sep-T1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a bug raised for this issue. Concerned team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any update.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Prasad-MSFT. Looking forward to test it once it's fixed.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, is the issue fixed?

Comment: Engineering team is still investigating the issue. We will inform you about updates. As a work around you can downgrade from 1.11 to 1.10. It works, we have checked as well.

Comment: This bug is resolved as part of the task module v2 feature on mobile platform. Since this is part of the overall feature, it will start rolling out to different internal rings first. This will be publicly available by May.

Comment: This bug has been fixed and is publicly available now. We tested it in below version, and it works fine now. https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJvMg.png

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this issue. To fix it, I downgraded `@microsoft/teams-js` from 1.11 to 1.10 and the modal began working as expected in iOS.